# Create a class with no instance methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I create a class with no instance methods defined? Not even `__send__` or `__id__`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the practicality in doing something like this?  It's very unclear as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Makoto why would one care about the practicality? When I google something, I never stumble upon Google saying: "Hey, why would you want to know if there is ** my search **. Are you sure you want to know that?"

Comment: @AndreyDeineko:  One of the things we use as a metric for questions [is if it's a practical problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I don't deny that this may be a stretch on my part, but I just can't see the practicality of creating a class that can't really be used in a conventional fashion.  I won't disparage the question further if one can provide a practical use case for it, but until then, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: @Makoto `It's very unclear as to what you want to achieve.` - it is crystal clear - ***class with no instance methods defined*** :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: It's unclear as to why one would want to achieve that.  Ruby is all about classes and instance methods.  Doesn't make sense why one *wouldn't* want that.

Comment: @Makoto One might want that for test purposes.  A method that is supposed to not care what an argument is, but just passes it on to something else, should work even for very unusual values for that argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Module#`undef_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) to undefine methods:

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  instance_methods.each { |method| undef_method(method) }
end

Foo.instance_methods #=> []
foo = Foo.new
foo.__id__           #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `__id__' for #<Foo:0x007fb9da565dd8>
foo.__send__(:test)  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `__send__' for #<Foo:0x007fb9da565dd8>
```

In this example `Foo` inherits from `BasicObject`, because this class itself has very few instance methods defined and thus, undefining them is faster. This is not obligatory, meaning, that you can undefine instance methods from any class no matter what it inherits from, so it could be very well written as:

```
class Foo
  instance_methods.each { |method| undef_method(method) }
end
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if this works, and all the methods are removed, then `undef_method` has to be the last one being undefined. It has to undefine itself. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: @sawa, `undef_method` is a (private) class method, so it wouldn't be removed. Welcome back.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why won't it be removed if it is private? Not as frequent as before, but I am occasionally around, especially when I feel my ranking might change.

Comment: @sawa, all instance methods of a given class are being removed, but the class' methods, including `undef_method` will remain, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Right. I had focused on the wrong word. That makes sense.

Comment: @sawa: `undef_method` is an instance method of `Module`, not `BasicObject`.

Comment: Upvote, but why `class Foo < BasicObject` rather than `class Foo`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just thought that undefining methods inherited from `BasicObjects` is faster, than undefining those inherited from `Object`. But this might not be a significant difference..